# getImageData() on Canvas return only 0 in all fields

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

To convert a PNG to raw data, I put it on a canvas and then request the image data. However, when I request the data, it only contains zeroes. However, if I draw with `.fillRect` it returns the color of the rectangle drawn. It is as if the inserted image is not really there in the eyes of `.getImageData`. I have tried setting a timeout on calling `.getImageData`, but it still doesn't return the correct data, so I believe that it is not a race condition.

This is for a Chrome plugin, so cross-platform is not an issue. I have also tried enabling/disabling hardware acceleration for Canvas.

Relevant code follows:

```
  var item = JQuery("<div style=\"width: 100%; border: 1px solid #b3b2b2; background: #c9c8c8; cursor: pointer; text-align: center;\"><h3 style=\"color: #8b8b8b; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400;\">Import</h3></div>");
  var imagebuffercont = JQuery("<canvas width=512 height=512 style=\"position: fixed; top: 25px; left: 25px; z-index: 9999;\"></canvas>").appendTo("body")[0].getContext("2d");

  var uploader = JQuery("<input type= \"file\" style=\"display:none\" />");
  uploader.change(function(){
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          var tmpelem = $('<img />');
          tmpelem.attr('src', e.target.result);

          imagebuffercont.drawImage(tmpelem[0], 0, 0);

          var imgbuffer = imagebuffercont.getImageData(0,0,512,512).data;
          var pixels = [];
          for (var j = 0; j<512; j++) {
            var tmprow = [];
            for (var i = 0; i<512*4; i += 4) {
              tmprow.push({
                red: imgbuffer[i],
                green: imgbuffer[i+1],
                blue: imgbuffer[i+2],
                alpha: imgbuffer[i+3]
              });
            }
            pixels.push(tmprow);
          }
          console.log(pixels);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally read the data incorrectly.

`for (var i = 0; i<512*4; i += 4) {` should be `for (var i = j*512*4; i<(j+1)*512*4; i += 4) {` or it would just constantly iterate over the first 512 pixels, that just so happened to be transparent...

Answer (score 0):

When you create image you should use onLoad event to continue processing it. Otherwise image is not ready when you put it to canvas. You should also include `drawImage` to onLoad event callback. Otherwise what happens is the empty picture is put on canvas.

You should modify the code to something like this:

```
      var tmpelem = $('<img />');
      tmpelem.on('load', function(){ /* Do all canvas stuff here*/ });
      tmpelem.attr('src', e.target.result);
```

Comment: I can see it before `getImageData` is called, but I'll try it later.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have drawn the image on Canvas (not entering that area). Just do

```
var img = imagebuffercont.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Variable img contains the raw data.
Please comment if there are any concerns.

Comment: Wouldn't that just return a Base 64 encoded PNG? I already get that from the uploader. I need access to the RGBA values for individual pixels.